# Conditionally merge lists

Tags: python, list, merge, conditional-statements

Say I have two lists

```
[16, 0, 0, ';', 17, 0, 2, ';', 0, 2, 1, ';']
  [-1, 0, ';', 0, -2, ';', -2, -1, ';']
```

Is there a simpler way to merge these list elements conditionally on meeting the ';' character than individually iterating through them both and combining them?

The output should be

```
[16, 0, 0, -1, 0, ';', 17, 0, 2, 0, -2, ';', 0, 2, 1, -2, -2,';']
```

Comment: Absolutely, thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
def get_part(lst,sep=';'):
    out = []
    for i in lst:
        if i == sep:
           yield out
           out = []
        else:
           out.append(i)
```

Now we can zip together your lists:

```
merged = []
for l1,l2 in zip(get_part(list1),get_part(list2)):
    merged.extend(l1)
    merged.extend(l2)
    merged.append(';')
```

Of course, at it's core, this is essentially iterating over both of them and combining ... so in answer to your question, I don't think there's a better way.

---

Perhaps a better way to store your lists would be storing them as a list of lists -- e.g.:

```
list1 = [[16, 0, 0], [ 17, 0, 2], [ 0, 2, 1] ]
```

stored like this, you can just do:

```
merged = [ l1 + l2 for l1,l2 in zip(list1,list2) ]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> from itertools import groupby, izip, chain
>>> L1=[16, 0, 0, ';', 17, 0, 2, ';', 0, 2, 1, ';']
>>> L2=[-1, 0, ';', 0, -2, ';', -2, -1, ';']    
>>> g1 = groupby(L1, key=';'.__eq__)
>>> g2 = groupby(L2, key=';'.__eq__)
>>> [i for i1,i2 in izip(g1, g2) for i in ([';'] if i1[0] is True else chain(i1[1], i2[1]))]
[16, 0, 0, -1, 0, ';', 17, 0, 2, 0, -2, ';', 0, 2, 1, -2, -1, ';']
```

Answer (score 1):

More itertools madness:

```
from itertools import groupby, chain, izip, repeat

a = [16, 0, 0, ';', 17, 0, 2, ';', 0, 2, 1, ';']
b = [-1, 0, ';', 0, -2, ';', -2, -1, ';']

wanted = [16, 0, 0, -1, 0, ";",
          17, 0, 2, 0, -2, ';',
          0, 2, 1, -2, -1,";"]

def split(items, sep=";"):
    return (group for key, group in
            groupby(items, lambda item: item != sep) if key)

got = list(
    chain.from_iterable(
        chain.from_iterable(
            izip(split(a), split(b), repeat([";"])))))
assert got == wanted
```