# Trim list to delimiter

Tags: python, list, trim, delimiter

Say you have the list

```
`[1, 0, -1, 0, ';', 2, 0, 0, -1, ';', 0, 1, 0, -1, ';', 0, 1, -2, 0, ';', 0, 3, -6, 0, ';']`
```

What is the easiest way to trim this backwards to say the second occurrence of ';', outputting

`[1, 0, -1, 0, ';', 2, 0, 0, -1, ';', 0, 1, 0, -1, ';', 0, 1, -2, 0]`

Comment: You want to trim a *string*, right? And get another *string* ?

Answer (score 5):

If you have a *list* as input, you can try to find the indices of the `";"` and work from there:

```
>>> L = [1, 0, -1, 0, ';', 2, 0, 0, -1, ';', 0, 1, 0, -1, ';', 0, 1, -2, 0, ';', 0, 3, -6, 0, ';']
>>> idx = [i for (i,v) in enumerate(L) if v == ";"]
>>> L[:idx[-2]]
[1, 0, -1, 0, ';', 2, 0, 0, -1, ';', 0, 1, 0, -1, ';', 0, 1, -2, 0, ';', 0, 3, -6, 0, ';']
```

Comment: This is nice.  I wish I had thought of it.

Answer (score 1):

```
def get_part(lst,sep=';'):
    out = []
    for i in lst:
        if i == sep:
           yield out
           out = []
        else:
           out.append(i)
```

(which you already have from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12424759/conditionally-merge-lists)).

Now, to trim it, we need to convert to a list:

```
lst = list(get_part(yourlist))
output_list = []
for part in lst[:-2]:
   output_list.extend(part)
   output_list.append(';')
```

---

But my previous advice still holds.  A better data structure is a list of lists.